# Setting the mouseup event inside a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

I have a single element on my page and i need to detect mosuedown and mouseup events. It works fine, but i decided to move all my javascript inside a class. this is what i came up with so far:

```js
class MyRectangle {
  constructor(elementId) {
    this.frame = $("#" + elementId);
    this.setListener();
  }

  setListener() {
    this.frame.on("mousedown", function(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      console.log("MOUSE DOWN" + " " + evt.pageX + ", " + evt.pageY);
      $(document).bind("mouseup", this.docMouseUp);
    });
  }

  docMouseUp(evt) {
    console.log("MOUSE UP" + " " + evt.pageX + ", " + evt.pageY);
    $(document).unbind("mouseup", this.docMouseUp);
  }

}

var myRect = new MyRectangle("rectangle");
```

```css
#rectangle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #dfca45;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rectangle">
</div>
```

This way, the mouseup event never triggers.

The JSFiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/5hd7672v/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that inside the `docMouseUp` and the callback for the `mousedown` event functions, `this` no longer refers to the `MyRectangle` instance. That is because these functions are invoked by `jQuery` and the context (the `this` variable) is set to the element that generated the event.

To fix that, you can bind the `MyRectangle` instance like this:

```
let self = this;
this.frame.on("mousedown", function(evt) { 
        evt.preventDefault();
        console.log("MOUSE DOWN" + " " + evt.pageX + ", " + evt.pageY);
        $(document).bind("mouseup", self.docMouseUp.bind(self));
});
```

EDIT

I've missed the `$(document).bind("mouseup", self.docMouseUp);` call.
In order to make that work, you'll need to change the reference to `docMouseUp` so it will point to the same function that was set as a callback.

```js
class MyRectangle {
    constructor(elementId) {
        this.frame = $("#" + elementId);
        this.setListener();
    }

    setListener() {
        let self = this;
        this.docMouseUp = this.docMouseUp.bind(this);
        
        this.frame.on("mousedown", function(evt) { 
            evt.preventDefault();
            console.log("MOUSE DOWN" + " " + evt.pageX + ", " + evt.pageY);
            $(document).bind("mouseup", self.docMouseUp);
        });
    }

    docMouseUp(evt) {
        console.log("MOUSE UP" + " " + evt.pageX + ", " + evt.pageY);
        $(document).unbind("mouseup", this.docMouseUp);     
    }

}

var myRect = new MyRectangle("rectangle");
```

```css
#rectangle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #dfca45;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rectangle">
</div>
```

Comment: It's better to use arrow functions than to save the current `this` reference in a separate variable - that's an anti-pattern.

Comment: @CertainPerformance It depends, in this case not using an arrow function has the advantage of letting `jQuery` set the context inside the anonymous function.

Comment: @CertainPerformance can't use them in IE for once: https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions

Comment: @Titus the unbind does not work properly. The callbacks stack up if you click more often.